# efficient management of PDF/files with zotero

Tags: reference-managers

I'm trying to introduce zotero in my research-flow. However, I don't find a way to efficiently manage the PDF files attached to entries of zotero. I use zotero with zotfile extension. The problems that I find:

- if the location of PDF is based on collections, if a move a reference to one collection or subcollection at another one, the PDF is not moved and remains in the old location.
- if I remove a reference, the PDF and the rest of attachments are not deleted.

So, at the end you have a mesh of folders with PDFs that you do not know if you can delete or not.

How do you work with attachments in zotero? Do you think that for example mendeley provides of better management of files/attachments?

Comment: You should ask this question on the Zotero support forum, which is quite active.

Comment: The golden solution is to store the PDFs in folder according to the authors' names using `zotfile`. Go to `Zotfile Preferences` and check the box `Use subfolder defined by`. The parameter for author based sorting is `/%a`